# Triangle proof using law of sines

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

> In triangle $ABC$, suppose that angle $C$ is twice angle $A$. Use the law of sines to show that $ab= c^2 - a^2$.

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, some would consider your post rude because it is a command ("show"), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it: if $\,a,b,c\,$ are the lengths of the sides opposite to vertices $\,A,B,C\,$ resp,. is then $\,ab=\,$ the product of lengths of sides BC and AC?

Comment: This is definitely off topic but since it illustrates a method that can be used to solve many similar problems, I would like to  add it as a comment.  By rescaling, we we can choose coordinates so that $C$ is the origin, $A$ is $(1,0)$ and $B$ is $(p,q)$ for suitable $p$ and $q$.  We can then express the quantities $a$, $b$, $c$, $\tan C$ and $\tan A$ as simple rational functions in $p$ and $q$.  Elementary algebra reduces both conditions to the  equality $3p^2+1=q^2+4p$ and so they are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Suggestions for getting started:

- Set $\angle C = 2\angle A$. And the measure of angle $B$ would then be $\pi - 3A$. Why?
- Use the law of Sines (or the reciprocal):

  $$ \frac{\sin A}{a} \,=\, \frac{\sin B}{b} \,=\, \frac{\sin C}{c}\quad\;\text{or}\quad
      \frac{a}{\sin A} \,=\, \frac{b}{\sin B} \,=\, \frac{c}{\sin C}$$ Substituting $2A$ for $C$, and use the double angle formula for $\sin C = \sin(2A)$. Substitute, as well $\sin B = \sin(\pi - 3A) = \sin(3A)$
- Make all possible substitutions, ***use trig identities***, and simplify, and see where that gets you, with your goal being to *relate the lengths of the sides as stated*.

We'll be happy to check your progress!

Answer (score 1):

Put $\,\angle C=2w\;,\;\;\angle A=w\;,\;\;\angle B=180- 3w\;$ , then

$$\frac{b}{\sin 3w}=\frac{c}{\sin 2w}=\frac{a}{\sin w}\implies ab=\frac{b^2\sin w}{\sin 3w}{}\;,\;\;a^2-c^2=\frac{b^2\sin^22w}{\sin^33w}-\frac{b^2\sin^2w}{\sin^23w}\implies$$

$$ab=c^2-a^2\iff \frac{b^2}{\sin 3w}\sin w=\frac{b^2}{\sin 3w}\left(\frac{\sin^22w}{\sin 3w}-\frac{\sin^2w}{\sin 3w}\right)\iff$$

$$\iff \sin w=\frac{\sin^22w-\sin^2w}{\sin 3w}=\frac{4\sin^2w\cos^2w-\sin^2w}{\sin 3w}\iff$$

$$\iff \frac{4\sin w\cos^2 w-\sin w}{\sin 3w}=1$$

But

$$(1)\;\;\;4\sin w\cos^2w-\sin w=\sin w(4\cos^2w-1)$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\sin 3w=\sin w\cos 2w+\sin 2w\cos w=\sin w(2\cos^2w-1)+2\sin w\cos^2w$$

Now just check that $\,(1)=(2)\;$...

Answer (score 1):

A common way to invoke the Law of Sines is to note what its ratios equal:

$$\frac{a}{\sin A} = \frac{b}{\sin B} = \frac{c}{\sin C} = d$$

where $d$ is the circum-diameter of $\triangle ABC$. Thus,

$$a = d \sin A \qquad b = d \sin B \qquad c = d \sin C$$

Consequently, the identity in question, upon division by $d^2$, is equivalent to

$$\sin A \sin B \stackrel{?}{=} \sin^2 C - \sin^2 A$$

Now, $C=2A$ implies $B=\pi-3A$, so that $\sin B = \sin 3A$, and the identity to be proven becomes

$$\begin{align}
\sin A \sin 3A &\stackrel{?}{=} \sin^2 2A - \sin^2 A \\[6pt]
&= \left( \sin 2A + \sin A \right) \left( \sin 2 A - \sin A \right) \\[6pt]
&= 2 \sin\frac{3A}{2}\cos\frac{A}{2} \cdot 2 \sin\frac{A}{2} \cos\frac{3A}{2} \\[6pt]
&= 2 \sin\frac{A}{2}\cos\frac{A}{2} \cdot 2 \sin\frac{3A}{2} \cos\frac{3A}{2} \\[6pt]
&= \sin A \; \sin 3A
\end{align}$$

In the above, I use the [sum-to-product identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) $\sin\theta \pm \sin\phi = 2 \sin\frac{\theta\pm \phi}{2} \cos\frac{\theta\mp \phi}{2}$, which is familiar to me. Someone familiar with [multiple-angle identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle.2C_triple-angle.2C_and_half-angle_formulae) may have proceeded thusly:

$$\begin{align}
\sin A \sin 3A &\stackrel{?}{=} \sin^2 2A - \sin^2 A \\[6pt]
&= 4\sin^2 A\cos^2 A - \sin^2 A \\[6pt]
&= \sin A \cdot \sin A \left( 4 \cos^2 A - 1 \right) \\[6pt]
&= \sin A \cdot \sin A \left( 3 - 4\sin^2 A \right) \\[6pt]
&= \sin A \; \sin 3A
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether I can submit this answer, but now that you know the proof through trigonometry, here's a different approach through simple geometry:

[image]

Look at the $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle CDB$, they are similar(Why?)

Lets call $AB=c$, $AC=b$ and $CB=a$. (As the usual notations)

Now from similarity we have, $\dfrac{b}{CD}=\dfrac{c}{a}=\dfrac{a}{DB}$

You will get the result with some manipulations(Get $DB$ in terms of sides of triangle).